# SQLite Boolean/Date DataTypes (or affinities)

Tags: android, sql, sqlite

I've done my research and from what I've read (SQLites data type weirdness aside) dates can be represented with integer, real and text and boolean can be represented with integer.

However I am going through an android book which has an example using DATE and want to know if maybe there are some modifications to Android's implementation of SQLite?

What actual datatype do I enter in my create statement for DATE,TIME, DATETIME and BOOLEAN?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no special handling for DATE in androids sqlite implementation. It follows the same affinity rules you have probably seen in the official sqlite docs here http://www.sqlite.org/datatype3.html

Hope that helps.

Comment: ty bro...so I'll use an actual INTEGER for both datetimes and booleans.

Comment: Cool integer is good. I store my dates in utc milliseconds that way it's easy to format and calculate offsets etc.